# Change Android USB Device Name for Windows Explorer

Tags: settings, usb

When I connect a Motorola Moto E (gen 2) using USB to a Windows 7 computer, the phone is shown in Windows Explorer as **"MotoE2(4G-LTE)"** which is a bit techie, but I know immediately what it is.

When I connect a Motorola Moto G (gen 2), it is shown as **"XT1072"** which I don't find very helpful.

[image: Windows Explorer screenshot]

I can edit the name in Windows Explorer, which is useful and permanent in that I later get that same new name if I connect the phone to a different computer.

However the popup on connection still uses the **XT1072** name

[image]

I assume the USB device name is determined by the phone. Can I change `XT1072` to something else (e.g. `MotoG2`) **in Android settings**?

Comment: This link [Change USB Model Name globally on the device](http://superuser.com/q/649181/183349) and this [Change USB Device Description](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/116963/18015) are related which might be helpful. And please also mention if your device is rooted or not and the Android version in your question. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just a name for the device that the manufacture put there. Change the name, call it what you like, it does not matter.

The pop up is part of Windows and will call on the device's real name (what the manufacturer called it). This device name is embedded into the your mobile device and can not be changed without going down to a low level of programming.

In your [phone spec on GSMarena](http://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_moto_g_4g_(2nd_gen)-7137.php), you will notice that your phone has multiple names.

Comment: @craig Instead of posting multiple answers, you should [edit] your answer and add the additional information that you want to provide.

Comment: Ok thanks the first post sorry will do next time